# matching a specific regex pattern with my string

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I would like my regex pattern to match a character with a pattern of 0-9 and multiply and add operator. So far this is what I have done.

```
var regexPattern = /\d\+\*/;

function matchPattern( regexPattern, mycharacter ) {
    if ( mycharacter.match( regexPattern ) ) {
        console.log( 'true' );
    } else {
        console.log( 'false' );
    }
}

matchPattern( regexPattern, '+' );
```

the problem is when I pass the pattern like a number or a '+' or '*' sign it returns false instead. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: oops. my bad, I was experimenting and experimenting different kinds of patterns and forgot to leave my original pattern that I have made. will change. thanks for spotting it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var regexPattern = [/\d\+\*/];
```

To this:

```
var regexPattern = /[\d\+\*]/;
```

Or, noting that you don't need to escape `+` or `*` when used within `[]`:

```
var regexPattern = /[\d+*]/;
```

You were creating an array containing a single element that is a regex. What you want is a regex that uses the `[]` as part of its pattern.

The pattern `[\d+*]` will match a digit (`\d`) or a plus sign (`+`) or an asterisk (`*`).

UPDATE for your edit: the pattern `/\d\+\*/` that you have will match a digit that is followed immediately by a plus sign that is followed by an asterisk. See above for the pattern you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the square brackets inside the regex: `/[\d\+\*]/` this means that it will match any of the characters in the square brackets.

To match more than just one character, you'll need to put a `+` or `*` on the end: `/[\d\+\*]+/` to tell it to keep matching any number of digits, asterisks and plus signs.